# How come the linq syntax work over the IQueryable interface in Rx Framework

Tags: c#-4.0, system.reactive

I've started looking over the reactive framework. Very nice stuff. But while looking at code samples it got me confused. The linq syntax works with the IQueryable. I thought that linq only works with IEnumerable. On what does the C# compiler bases it's linq to extension methods conversions? Does it require a set of methods with a specific interface?

Comment: LINQ has always worked with `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite. It's just a syntactic translation. For example, the compiler will translate this:

```
var query = from item in source
            select item.Property;
```

into

```
var query = source.Select(item => item.Property);
```

It does that without knowing anything about the `Select` method. It just does the translation, then tries to compile the translated code.

All the translations are carefully documented in section 7.16 of the C# 4 spec (and the equivalent for earlier editions, of course).

In the case of Rx, it calls the extensions on `IObservable<T>` and `IQbservable<T>`. In the case of Parallel Extensions, it calls the extension methods on `ParallelQuery<T>`.

You can do some *mad* stuff with it - I have a [blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/02/29/odd-query-expressions.aspx) which gives a few examples. Here's another odd one:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace CornerCases
{
    class WeirdQueryExpression
    {
        static WeirdQueryExpression Where(Func<int, int> projection)
        {
            return new WeirdQueryExpression { Select = ignored => "result!" };
        }

        Func<Func<string, bool>, string> Select { get; set; }

        static void Main()
        {
            string query = from x in WeirdQueryExpression
                           where x * 3
                           select x.Length > 10;

            Console.WriteLine(query);
        }
    }
}
```

The query translates to:

```
WeirdQueryExpression.Where(x => x * 3)
                    .Select(x => x.Length > 10);
```

... which is a call to a static method, which returns a `WeirdQueryExpression`, followed by accessing the `Where` property which returns a `Func<Func<string, bool>, string>`. We then *call* that delegate (passing in another delegate) and assign the result to `query`.

Funky, huh?

Comment: Just to add (in order to help the OP), LINQ finds the extension methods for IQueryable via the Queryable class:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aspx